# What is the maximum size of the texture memory on a modern GPU?

Tags: memory, cuda, textures, gpgpu, nvidia

We believe that texture memory is part of the global memory, is this true? If so, how much can you allocate? (Indirectly, how much is there?)

And is it true that all multiprocessors can read from the texture memory at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Texture data is contained in CUDA arrays, and CUDA arrays are allocated out of global memory; so however much global memory is still free (you can call cuMemGetInfo() to see how much free memory is left) is available for allocation as textures.

It's impossible to know how much memory is consumed by a given CUDA array - obviously it has to be at least Width*Height*Depth*sizeof(Texel), but it may take more because the driver has to do an allocation that conforms to the hardware's alignment requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Texture limits for different compute capabilities can be found in the CUDA Programming Guide, available at the [NVIDIA CUDA website](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html).

For a given device, one can query device capabilities including texture limits using the [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html) function.

Allocation depends on the amount of available global memory and the segmentation of the memory, so there is no easy way to tell whether a given allocation will be successfull or not, especially when working with large textures.